# How to align a DIV element at the center of the remaining free space with Bootstrap v5.1

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I'm a completely novice with front-end developing but I'm trying to build my website to showcase my Blockchain's projects.

Right now, I am trying to align the text "Technology is my Passion" at the vertical-center of the remaining free space.

**How do I achieve this with bootstrap v5.1?**

**Is it possible to achieve a generalized answer as the image below?**

[image]

---

**CODE SNIPPET**

```css
/*--- basic styling ---*/
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Hack, monospace !important;
    background-color: #0f0f0f !important;
}

.owner {
        color: #F4364C;
        font-size: 1.2vw;
}

/*--- glitch effect ---*/
.glitch {
      color: #F4364C;
      position: relative;
      font-size: 4vw !important;
}

.glitch::before {
      color: #F4364C;
      position: absolute;
      content: attr(data-text);
      top: 0vh;
      left: 0.3vw;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-shadow: -1px 0 #FFD700;
      background: #0f0f0f;
      overflow: hidden;
      animation: glitch-anim-1 2s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
    
.glitch::after {
      color: #F4364C;
      position: absolute;
      content: attr(data-text);
      top: 0vh;
      right: 0.3vw;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-shadow: -1px 0 #C0C0C0;
      background: #0f0f0f;
      overflow: hidden;
      animation: glitch-anim-2 2s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
    
@-webkit-keyframes glitch-anim-1 {
      0% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(37% 0 1% 0);
            clip-path: inset(37% 0 1% 0);
      }
      5% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(46% 0 40% 0);
            clip-path: inset(46% 0 40% 0);
      }
      10% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(99% 0 1% 0);
            clip-path: inset(99% 0 1% 0);
      }
      15% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(91% 0 6% 0);
            clip-path: inset(91% 0 6% 0);
      }
      20% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(11% 0 37% 0);
            clip-path: inset(11% 0 37% 0);
      }
      25% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(97% 0 1% 0);
            clip-path: inset(97% 0 1% 0);
      }
      30% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(24% 0 56% 0);
            clip-path: inset(24% 0 56% 0);
      }
      35% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(20% 0 30% 0);
            clip-path: inset(20% 0 30% 0);
      }
      40% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(89% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(89% 0 8% 0);
      }
      45% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(36% 0 60% 0);
            clip-path: inset(36% 0 60% 0);
      }
      50% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(5% 0 62% 0);
            clip-path: inset(5% 0 62% 0);
      }
      55% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(9% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(9% 0 3% 0);
      }
      60% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(50% 0 21% 0);
            clip-path: inset(50% 0 21% 0);
      }
      65% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
      }
      70% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(68% 0 15% 0);
            clip-path: inset(68% 0 15% 0);
      }
      75% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(47% 0 49% 0);
            clip-path: inset(47% 0 49% 0);
      }
      80% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(90% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(90% 0 3% 0);
      }
      85% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(97% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(97% 0 3% 0);
      }
      90% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(45% 0 29% 0);
            clip-path: inset(45% 0 29% 0);
      }
      95% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
            clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
      }
      100% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(46% 0 12% 0);
            clip-path: inset(46% 0 12% 0);
      }
}
    
@keyframes glitch-anim-1 {
      0% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(37% 0 1% 0);
            clip-path: inset(37% 0 1% 0);
      }
      5% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(46% 0 40% 0);
            clip-path: inset(46% 0 40% 0);
      }
      10% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(99% 0 1% 0);
            clip-path: inset(99% 0 1% 0);
      }
      15% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(91% 0 6% 0);
            clip-path: inset(91% 0 6% 0);
      }
      20% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(11% 0 37% 0);
            clip-path: inset(11% 0 37% 0);
      }
      25% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(97% 0 1% 0);
            clip-path: inset(97% 0 1% 0);
      }
      30% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(24% 0 56% 0);
            clip-path: inset(24% 0 56% 0);
      }
      35% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(20% 0 30% 0);
            clip-path: inset(20% 0 30% 0);
      }
      40% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(89% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(89% 0 8% 0);
      }
      45% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(36% 0 60% 0);
            clip-path: inset(36% 0 60% 0);
      }
      50% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(5% 0 62% 0);
            clip-path: inset(5% 0 62% 0);
      }
      55% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(9% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(9% 0 3% 0);
      }
      60% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(50% 0 21% 0);
            clip-path: inset(50% 0 21% 0);
      }
      65% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
      }
      70% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(68% 0 15% 0);
            clip-path: inset(68% 0 15% 0);
      }
      75% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(47% 0 49% 0);
            clip-path: inset(47% 0 49% 0);
      }
      80% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(90% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(90% 0 3% 0);
      }
      85% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(97% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(97% 0 3% 0);
      }
      90% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(45% 0 29% 0);
            clip-path: inset(45% 0 29% 0);
      }
      95% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
            clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
      }
      100% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(46% 0 12% 0);
            clip-path: inset(46% 0 12% 0);
      }
}
    
@-webkit-keyframes glitch-anim-2 {
      0% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(35% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(35% 0 4% 0);
      }
      5% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
            clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
      }
      10% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(37% 0 13% 0);
            clip-path: inset(37% 0 13% 0);
      }
      15% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(86% 0 2% 0);
            clip-path: inset(86% 0 2% 0);
      }
      20% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(37% 0 22% 0);
            clip-path: inset(37% 0 22% 0);
      }
      25% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(36% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(36% 0 4% 0);
      }
      30% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(85% 0 10% 0);
            clip-path: inset(85% 0 10% 0);
      }
      35% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(40% 0 13% 0);
            clip-path: inset(40% 0 13% 0);
      }
      40% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(6% 0 69% 0);
            clip-path: inset(6% 0 69% 0);
      }
      45% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(6% 0 11% 0);
            clip-path: inset(6% 0 11% 0);
      }
      50% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
      }
      55% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(70% 0 9% 0);
            clip-path: inset(70% 0 9% 0);
      }
      60% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(23% 0 71% 0);
            clip-path: inset(23% 0 71% 0);
      }
      65% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
      }
      70% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(74% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(74% 0 8% 0);
      }
      75% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(72% 0 23% 0);
            clip-path: inset(72% 0 23% 0);
      }
      80% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(71% 0 9% 0);
            clip-path: inset(71% 0 9% 0);
      }
      85% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(52% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(52% 0 3% 0);
      }
      90% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(42% 0 46% 0);
            clip-path: inset(42% 0 46% 0);
      }
      95% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
      }
      100% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(55% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(55% 0 4% 0);
      }
}
    
@keyframes glitch-anim-2 {
      0% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(35% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(35% 0 4% 0);
      }
      5% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
            clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
      }
      10% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(37% 0 13% 0);
            clip-path: inset(37% 0 13% 0);
      }
      15% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(86% 0 2% 0);
            clip-path: inset(86% 0 2% 0);
      }
      20% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(37% 0 22% 0);
            clip-path: inset(37% 0 22% 0);
      }
      25% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(36% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(36% 0 4% 0);
      }
      30% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(85% 0 10% 0);
            clip-path: inset(85% 0 10% 0);
      }
      35% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(40% 0 13% 0);
            clip-path: inset(40% 0 13% 0);
      }
      40% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(6% 0 69% 0);
            clip-path: inset(6% 0 69% 0);
      }
      45% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(6% 0 11% 0);
            clip-path: inset(6% 0 11% 0);
      }
      50% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
      }
      55% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(70% 0 9% 0);
            clip-path: inset(70% 0 9% 0);
      }
      60% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(23% 0 71% 0);
            clip-path: inset(23% 0 71% 0);
      }
      65% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
      }
      70% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(74% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(74% 0 8% 0);
      }
      75% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(72% 0 23% 0);
            clip-path: inset(72% 0 23% 0);
      }
      80% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(71% 0 9% 0);
            clip-path: inset(71% 0 9% 0);
      }
      85% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(52% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(52% 0 3% 0);
      }
      90% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(42% 0 46% 0);
            clip-path: inset(42% 0 46% 0);
      }
      95% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
      }
      100% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(55% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(55% 0 4% 0);
      }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <meta name="author" content="Joshua">
      
      <title>XXX's Website | XXX</title>
      
      <!-- stylesheet -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      
      <!-- bootstrap cdns -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
      integrity="sha384-uWxY/CJNBR+1zjPWmfnSnVxwRheevXITnMqoEIeG1LJrdI0GlVs/9cVSyPYXdcSF" crossorigin="anonymous">
      
      <!-- hack fonts -->
      <link href='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hack-font@3.3.0/build/web/hack.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 min-vw-100">
            <!-- owner -->
            <div class="container-fluid owner">
                  <p class="text-left">I'm XXX XXX</p>
            </div>
            <!-- nav bar -->

            <!-- main phrase -->
            <div class="container-fluid">
                  <p class="text-center h1 glitch" data-text="Technology is my Passion">Technology is my Passion</p>
            </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to apply the class `my-auto` it sets the margins on the y-axis to auto, thus centering it vertically within the available space.

```css
/*--- basic styling ---*/
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Hack, monospace !important;
    background-color: #0f0f0f !important;
}

.owner {
        color: #F4364C;
        font-size: 1.2vw;
}

/*--- glitch effect ---*/
.glitch {
      color: #F4364C;
      position: relative;
      font-size: 4vw !important;
}

.glitch::before {
      color: #F4364C;
      position: absolute;
      content: attr(data-text);
      top: 0vh;
      left: 0.3vw;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-shadow: -1px 0 #FFD700;
      background: #0f0f0f;
      overflow: hidden;
      animation: glitch-anim-1 2s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
    
.glitch::after {
      color: #F4364C;
      position: absolute;
      content: attr(data-text);
      top: 0vh;
      right: 0.3vw;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-shadow: -1px 0 #C0C0C0;
      background: #0f0f0f;
      overflow: hidden;
      animation: glitch-anim-2 2s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
    
@-webkit-keyframes glitch-anim-1 {
      0% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(37% 0 1% 0);
            clip-path: inset(37% 0 1% 0);
      }
      5% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(46% 0 40% 0);
            clip-path: inset(46% 0 40% 0);
      }
      10% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(99% 0 1% 0);
            clip-path: inset(99% 0 1% 0);
      }
      15% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(91% 0 6% 0);
            clip-path: inset(91% 0 6% 0);
      }
      20% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(11% 0 37% 0);
            clip-path: inset(11% 0 37% 0);
      }
      25% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(97% 0 1% 0);
            clip-path: inset(97% 0 1% 0);
      }
      30% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(24% 0 56% 0);
            clip-path: inset(24% 0 56% 0);
      }
      35% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(20% 0 30% 0);
            clip-path: inset(20% 0 30% 0);
      }
      40% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(89% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(89% 0 8% 0);
      }
      45% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(36% 0 60% 0);
            clip-path: inset(36% 0 60% 0);
      }
      50% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(5% 0 62% 0);
            clip-path: inset(5% 0 62% 0);
      }
      55% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(9% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(9% 0 3% 0);
      }
      60% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(50% 0 21% 0);
            clip-path: inset(50% 0 21% 0);
      }
      65% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
      }
      70% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(68% 0 15% 0);
            clip-path: inset(68% 0 15% 0);
      }
      75% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(47% 0 49% 0);
            clip-path: inset(47% 0 49% 0);
      }
      80% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(90% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(90% 0 3% 0);
      }
      85% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(97% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(97% 0 3% 0);
      }
      90% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(45% 0 29% 0);
            clip-path: inset(45% 0 29% 0);
      }
      95% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
            clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
      }
      100% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(46% 0 12% 0);
            clip-path: inset(46% 0 12% 0);
      }
}
    
@keyframes glitch-anim-1 {
      0% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(37% 0 1% 0);
            clip-path: inset(37% 0 1% 0);
      }
      5% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(46% 0 40% 0);
            clip-path: inset(46% 0 40% 0);
      }
      10% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(99% 0 1% 0);
            clip-path: inset(99% 0 1% 0);
      }
      15% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(91% 0 6% 0);
            clip-path: inset(91% 0 6% 0);
      }
      20% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(11% 0 37% 0);
            clip-path: inset(11% 0 37% 0);
      }
      25% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(97% 0 1% 0);
            clip-path: inset(97% 0 1% 0);
      }
      30% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(24% 0 56% 0);
            clip-path: inset(24% 0 56% 0);
      }
      35% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(20% 0 30% 0);
            clip-path: inset(20% 0 30% 0);
      }
      40% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(89% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(89% 0 8% 0);
      }
      45% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(36% 0 60% 0);
            clip-path: inset(36% 0 60% 0);
      }
      50% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(5% 0 62% 0);
            clip-path: inset(5% 0 62% 0);
      }
      55% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(9% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(9% 0 3% 0);
      }
      60% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(50% 0 21% 0);
            clip-path: inset(50% 0 21% 0);
      }
      65% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
      }
      70% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(68% 0 15% 0);
            clip-path: inset(68% 0 15% 0);
      }
      75% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(47% 0 49% 0);
            clip-path: inset(47% 0 49% 0);
      }
      80% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(90% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(90% 0 3% 0);
      }
      85% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(97% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(97% 0 3% 0);
      }
      90% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(45% 0 29% 0);
            clip-path: inset(45% 0 29% 0);
      }
      95% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
            clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
      }
      100% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(46% 0 12% 0);
            clip-path: inset(46% 0 12% 0);
      }
}
    
@-webkit-keyframes glitch-anim-2 {
      0% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(35% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(35% 0 4% 0);
      }
      5% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
            clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
      }
      10% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(37% 0 13% 0);
            clip-path: inset(37% 0 13% 0);
      }
      15% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(86% 0 2% 0);
            clip-path: inset(86% 0 2% 0);
      }
      20% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(37% 0 22% 0);
            clip-path: inset(37% 0 22% 0);
      }
      25% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(36% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(36% 0 4% 0);
      }
      30% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(85% 0 10% 0);
            clip-path: inset(85% 0 10% 0);
      }
      35% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(40% 0 13% 0);
            clip-path: inset(40% 0 13% 0);
      }
      40% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(6% 0 69% 0);
            clip-path: inset(6% 0 69% 0);
      }
      45% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(6% 0 11% 0);
            clip-path: inset(6% 0 11% 0);
      }
      50% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
      }
      55% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(70% 0 9% 0);
            clip-path: inset(70% 0 9% 0);
      }
      60% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(23% 0 71% 0);
            clip-path: inset(23% 0 71% 0);
      }
      65% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
      }
      70% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(74% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(74% 0 8% 0);
      }
      75% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(72% 0 23% 0);
            clip-path: inset(72% 0 23% 0);
      }
      80% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(71% 0 9% 0);
            clip-path: inset(71% 0 9% 0);
      }
      85% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(52% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(52% 0 3% 0);
      }
      90% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(42% 0 46% 0);
            clip-path: inset(42% 0 46% 0);
      }
      95% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
      }
      100% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(55% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(55% 0 4% 0);
      }
}
    
@keyframes glitch-anim-2 {
      0% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(35% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(35% 0 4% 0);
      }
      5% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
            clip-path: inset(84% 0 10% 0);
      }
      10% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(37% 0 13% 0);
            clip-path: inset(37% 0 13% 0);
      }
      15% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(86% 0 2% 0);
            clip-path: inset(86% 0 2% 0);
      }
      20% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(37% 0 22% 0);
            clip-path: inset(37% 0 22% 0);
      }
      25% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(36% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(36% 0 4% 0);
      }
      30% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(85% 0 10% 0);
            clip-path: inset(85% 0 10% 0);
      }
      35% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(40% 0 13% 0);
            clip-path: inset(40% 0 13% 0);
      }
      40% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(6% 0 69% 0);
            clip-path: inset(6% 0 69% 0);
      }
      45% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(6% 0 11% 0);
            clip-path: inset(6% 0 11% 0);
      }
      50% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
      }
      55% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(70% 0 9% 0);
            clip-path: inset(70% 0 9% 0);
      }
      60% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(23% 0 71% 0);
            clip-path: inset(23% 0 71% 0);
      }
      65% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 4% 0);
      }
      70% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(74% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(74% 0 8% 0);
      }
      75% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(72% 0 23% 0);
            clip-path: inset(72% 0 23% 0);
      }
      80% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(71% 0 9% 0);
            clip-path: inset(71% 0 9% 0);
      }
      85% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(52% 0 3% 0);
            clip-path: inset(52% 0 3% 0);
      }
      90% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(42% 0 46% 0);
            clip-path: inset(42% 0 46% 0);
      }
      95% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
            clip-path: inset(93% 0 8% 0);
      }
      100% {
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(55% 0 4% 0);
            clip-path: inset(55% 0 4% 0);
      }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <meta name="author" content="Joshua">
      
      <title>XXX's Website | XXX</title>
      
      <!-- stylesheet -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      
      <!-- bootstrap cdns -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
      integrity="sha384-uWxY/CJNBR+1zjPWmfnSnVxwRheevXITnMqoEIeG1LJrdI0GlVs/9cVSyPYXdcSF" crossorigin="anonymous">
      
      <!-- hack fonts -->
      <link href='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hack-font@3.3.0/build/web/hack.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 min-vw-100">
            <!-- owner -->
            <div class="container-fluid owner">
                  <p class="text-left">I'm XXX XXX</p>
            </div>
            <!-- nav bar -->

            <!-- main phrase -->
            <div class="container-fluid my-auto">
                  <p class="text-center h1 glitch" data-text="Technology is my Passion">Technology is my Passion</p>
            </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```